# Compact Riemann Surface

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Let's consider the $\mathbb{Z}-$Action on $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ given by, for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, $k\cdot z:= q^kz$, with a fixed $q\in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ such that $0<|q|<1$.

I have to prove that $\mathbb{C}^{\times}/q^{\mathbb{Z}}$ is a compact Riemann surface that is isomorphic to a complex torus $\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\tau)$ for some $\tau\in \mathbb{C}$.

I really don't know how to start. Anyone knows how to prove this?

Comment: The trick is to find a so-called fundamental region: a connected open set that contains at most one element from each equivalence class, and whose closure contains an element from each class. It’s not hard to see the answer if, say, $q=1/2$. Then generalize.

Comment: and if there is a fondamental region, what do I conclude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Try to obtain a fundamental domain for this action, e.g. analyzing what is the orbit of the circle $S^1=\{z\,|\,||z||=1\}$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: @Jackristin: have you seen how $\Bbb R^2/\Bbb Z^2$ is a torus? You first show that the square $[0,1]^2$ is a fundamental domain of the action (the points are in 1-1 correspondence with the orbits except possibly for boundary points), then you glue the boundary together according to the action. Here you do in an analogous way.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with algebraic geometry, how does this prove that is a compact RS? Does It follow from the fact that the fundamental domain is compact?

Comment: @Jackristin: in fact this has little to do with algebraic geometry proper, it's more a basic topological technique. If the fundamental domain has compact closure then the Riemann surface you obtain is compact.

Comment: I'm having some troubles finding this theorem in letterature. Do you have any reference for your statement?

Comment: @Jackristin: it's a simple topological fact. Let $G$ be a group acting as homeomorphisms on the topological space $X$ and let $F\subset X$ be a fundamental domain for the action. Then there's a surjective continuous map $\bar F\rightarrow X/G$. If $\bar F$ is compact also $X/G$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

> It is supposedly obvious that $\Bbb{C/(Z+\tau Z)}$ is a compact Riemann surface (for $\tau\not \in \Bbb{R}$)

The isomorphism to $\Bbb{C^\times/q^Z}$ is $$z+\Bbb{Z+\tau Z}\to \exp(2i\pi z) q^\Bbb{Z}, \qquad q=\exp(2i\pi \tau)$$